# Music player not changing volume in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a React Music Player but I don't know why, the volume is not updating in real time. The volume only changes whenever I stop the audio and then play it again.

```
const [volume, setVolume] = useState(1)
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const audioRef = React.createRef();

    const togglePlay = () => {
        const audio = audioRef.current;

        if (!audio) return;

        audio.volume = volume;

        if (isPlaying) {
            audio.volume = 0;
        } else {
            audio.volume = Number(volume);
            audio.play();
            console.log(volume)
        }

        setIsPlaying((prevIsPlaying) => !prevIsPlaying);
    };
```

The input:

```
<input type="range" value={volume} onChange={(e) => setVolume(parseFloat(e.target.value))} max="1" min="0"/>
```

I've tried to use Chat-GPT to help me fix this error

Comment: State variables are updated when a re-render happens.  Since you want the change in audio volume to happen immediately, a state variable isn’t really suitable. use `audio.volume = parseFloat(…)` in the onChange function

Comment: Where is the code for your audio player? It looks like your input is correct. You may also need a `React.useEffect` where you listen to `[volume]` and then do `audioRef.current.volume = volumne`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [useEffect](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/) React hook, in order to keep the state data consistent with the (HTML) Audio object.

So every time either `volume` or `isPlaying` variable is changed, the hook is then executed, and by comparing the values of the actual Audio object and your state, you would depending on the variable changed; either call the Audio API or change the Audio refs value.

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [volume, setVolume] = React.useState(0.3);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(false);
  const audioRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
      const audio = audioRef.current;
      if (!audio) return;
      if (audio.volume !== volume) {
        audio.volume = volume;
      }
      if (!audio.paused !== isPlaying) {
        isPlaying ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
      }
  }, [volume, isPlaying]);

  const togglePlay = () => {
    setIsPlaying((prevIsPlaying) => !prevIsPlaying);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <audio volume={volume} ref={audioRef}>
        <source src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/theme_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
      </audio>
      <input type="range" step="0.1" value={volume} onChange={(e) => setVolume(parseFloat(e.target.value))} max="1" min="0"/>
      <button onClick={togglePlay}>{isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

*PS: Remember, autoplay is usually blocked by browsers.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 0):

How about to use useEffect hook?
Like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
   const audio = audioRef.current;
   if (!audio) return;
   audio.volume = volume;
}, [volume]);
```